# INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT:longMsg=java.lang.illegalArgumentException

Tags: android, unit-testing, instrumentation

In the directory:/packages/apps/Contacts/tests/, build and I got the `ContactsTest.apk`

Install the ContactsTest.apk to the device.

Execute the command:

```
adb shell am instrument -e class com.android.contacts.activities.OnStarContactEditorActivityTest#testInitial -w com.android.contacts.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

It throws the exception:

> INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT:longMsg=java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Unknown Action String android.intnet.action.MAIN. Only support com.gm.contacts.action.EDIT_CONTACT..............

Answer (score 0):

I don't why the exception occur, but it can be fix as follows:
add setActivityIntent(new Intent("com.gm.contacts.action.CREATE_CONTACT"));
before getActivity().